# Change orientation of iText PdfPTable

Tags: itext

This is what I'm getting. How can I rotate the table as well - not just the document. The columns could be wider if the table was rotated.[image: resulting document]

The code below reproduces the problem on a smaller scale with just 1 column.

```
private void exportTableAsPDF(File outputFile) {

    // PDF document
    Document pdfDocument = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        // Used to rotate the page - iText recommended this approach in an answer to a question referenced below
        // https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-page-while-creating-pdf-document
        class RotateEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
            public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
                writer.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE, PdfPage.SEASCAPE);
            }
        }

        // Rotates each page to landscape
        pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new RotateEvent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pdfDocument.open();

    // PDF table
    PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(1);

    // Add column header cell
    PdfPCell dateCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date"));
    pdfPTable.addCell(dateCell);

    // Gets cell data
    LogEntryMapper logEntryMapper = new LogEntryMapper();
    List<LogEntry> logEntries = logEntryMapper.readAll();

    // Adds a cell to the table with "date" data
    for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
        dateCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(logEntry.getLogEntryDate()));
        pdfPTable.addCell(dateCell);
    }

    // Adds the table to the pdf document
    try {
        pdfDocument.add(pdfPTable);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

This code block produces the following result.[image]

Comment: Please show us a minimal code sample that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @JorisSchellekens I've added my code per your request.

Comment: So you essentially want a landscape page filled upright?

Comment: @mkl That sounds correct, yes. The table should be rotated 90° clockwise so that the user can read the table from left to right while maintaining a landscape page orientation.

Comment: Ok. For that you don't need a page event listener. It suffices to use an appropriate page size as parameter of  `Document` constructor.

Comment: @mkl Well, your answer definitely answers the question. Unfortunately, the table width doesn't change and therefore doesn't make use of the extra space given by new page dimensions. Nevertheless, I'll still accept your answer as the solution if you post one since it does indeed give the effect of a landscape page with a portrait table. (Though it would be awesome if you knew of a way to increase the width of the table to match the increase in the width of the document.)

Comment: I just tried it, taking your code, replacing the `new Document()` by `new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate())` and removing the page event listener, and the table *does* make use of the extra space. Did you probably test with your multi-column table? And do you probably set absolute column widths in that code?

Comment: @mkl It works! Fantastic! Please post an answer so I can accept it. I think it might be to your upvoting benefit to include something about being able to adjust the margins too for anyone who might be wondering
`Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom)` My problem when trying your suggestion earlier was that I was using my own dimensions `Document(700, 400)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you found (with the page event listener) is for a different problem: It is for printing upright on the document paper size and then rotating the page including the content. For your problem (printing upright on a rotated paper) you only need to initialize the document with a rotated paper size:

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

This way the table makes use of the additional page size.

You will notice, though, that there still is some free space both left and right. There are two reasons for that:

- tables respect the page margins configured for the document;
- tables by default only use 80% of the width available.

You can, therefore, reduce that free space left and right by

- reducing the page margins, e.g. by using yet another `Document` constructor

  ```
  Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(),
                                      marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
  ```

  or by using `pdfDocument.setMargins(marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom)` before the page in question is created;
- increasing the percentage of the available width used by the table

  ```
  pdfPTable.setWidthPercentage(widthPercentage);
  ```

  using a `widthPercentage` value of e.g. `100`.