# Datagridview To Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview

It saves all the information in the datagridview as pdf to the location I want.
I am exporting Data to PDF in Datagridview.
What I want is to transfer the selected row. Adjusting the paper horizontally.
I'm trying to prepare a program. I do not have too much information.

```
 if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
      SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
      sfd.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
      sfd.FileName = "Veriler PDF.pdf";
      bool fileError = false;
      if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
          {
              try
              {
                  File.Delete(sfd.FileName);
              }
              catch (IOException ex)
              {
                  fileError = true;
                  MessageBox.Show("Verileri Dönüştürmek Mümkün Olmadı." + ex.Message);
              }
          }
          if (!fileError)
          {
              try
              {                                                        
                  PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
                  pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
                  pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
                  pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                     
                  foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                  {
                      PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                      cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240); // İlk Satır hücre arka plan rengi
                      pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
                  }

                  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                  {
                      foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                      {
                          pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                      }
                  }

                  using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                  {
                      Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 10f, 20f, 20f, 10f);
                      PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                      pdfDoc.Open();
                      pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
                      pdfDoc.Close();
                      stream.Close();
                  }

                  MessageBox.Show("Veriler PDF'ye Dönüştürüldü", "Info");
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Dışa Aktarılacak Kayıt Yok !!!", "Info");
  }
```

I'm waiting for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change orientation of iText PdfPTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140356/change-orientation-of-itext-pdfptable)